# In Android, the tabs won't accept textAllCaps as false, why?

Tags: android, tabs, android-theme

Based on some SO and other page I've added the option to turn off all caps on my tabs:

```
<style name="ScreenTransition.Activity" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/screen_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/screen_out</item>
</style>

<style name="tabTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="ScreenTransition" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ScreenTransition.Activity</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/tabTheme</item>
</style>
```

I have this declared in my manifest:

```
<android:theme="@style/ScreenTransition" >
```

The first part handles the screen transitions the second I want to use to style my tabs. I know "ScreenTransition" is a poor theme name (now) I'll change the name to something more generic later.

My transitions work fine but it's not applying the

`<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>`

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock or ActionBarCompat?

Comment: no, everything is native